# How to get the serial Number of USB device with golang?

Tags: go, usb, serial-number

How to get the serial Number of USB device with golang ?

Is there any example code ?

Anyone who know !

Comment: Does this help you? [gousb](https://github.com/kylelemons/gousb), doc is at [godoc](https://godoc.org/github.com/kylelemons/gousb)

Comment: If you are on unix/osx use system commands.

Answer (score 1):

You must use a wrapper of libusb in golang (an example is [gousb](https://github.com/kylelemons/gousb)).
But this wrapper doesn't have the command in order to get the serial number.
So you have to implement it. The command in libusb in order to do this is:

```
C.libusb_get_string_descriptor_ascii
```

Answer (score 0):

The [libusb](https://github.com/gotmc/libusb/) Go package has a method [`GetStringDesciptorASCII`](https://godoc.org/github.com/gotmc/libusb#DeviceHandle.GetStringDescriptorASCII) that can be used to get the S/N of a USB device.

### Example without error handling

```
package main

import (
    "log"

    "github.com/gotmc/libusb"
)

func main() {
    ctx, _ := libusb.Init()
    defer ctx.Exit()
    devices, _ := ctx.GetDeviceList()
    for _, device := range devices {
        usbDeviceDescriptor, _ := device.GetDeviceDescriptor()
        handle, _ := device.Open()
        defer handle.Close()
        snIndex := usbDeviceDescriptor.SerialNumberIndex
        serialNumber, _ := handle.GetStringDescriptorASCII(snIndex)
        log.Printf("Found S/N: %s", serialNumber)
    }
}
```

Comment: I got the error when I `go get github.com/gotmc/libusb`

Comment: `
bjbus@bjbus:~$ go get github.com/gotmc/libusb
# pkg-config --cflags libusb-1.0 libusb-1.0 libusb-1.0 libusb-1.0 libusb-1.0 
...
to the PKG_CONFIG_PATH environment variable
Package libusb-1.0 was not found in the pkg-config search path.
Perhaps you should add the directory containing `libusb-1.0.pc'
to the PKG_CONFIG_PATH environment variable
No package 'libusb-1.0' found
...
pkg-config: exit status 1
`

Comment: I retry  `go get github.com/gotmc/libusb` after `apt-get install libusb-1.0-0-dev`. and got the message: `could not determine kind of name for C.LIBUSB_TRANSFER_TYPE_BULK_STREAM`

Comment: @sope Did you also perform `sudo apt-get install libusb-1.0-0`? I'm not sure if `libusb-1.0-0-dev` installs the `libusb-1.0-0` dependency or not.

Comment: libusb-1.0-0  has already been installed default in ubuntu 14.04

Comment: Thank you for your replay. I forked the gousb and implemented C.libusb_get_string_descriptor_ascii with golang.